# Не осуществляется плавный переход на странице (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

Есть сайт http://implant.alba-avis.dental/

Есть следующий код, который осуществляет плавный переход (по клику на пункт меню) до определенного якоря:

```
jQuery('a[href^="#"]').click(function () { 
    elementClick = jQuery(this).attr("href");
    destination = jQuery(elementClick).offset().top;
    jQuery('html,body').animate( { scrollTop: (destination - 140) }, 1100 );        
    return false;
});
```

как мы видим:

1. в elementClick записываем искомый элемент
2. в destination - расстояние элемента от "потолка"
3. осуществляем мягкий переход до заданой точки (за минусом 140 пикселей)

если заглянуть в код этой страницы, то можно увидеть, что данные еще и в консоль выводятся. Так вот, что меня удивляет - сам переход не осуществляется, но если строку

```
jQuery('html,body').animate( { scrollTop: (destination - 140) }, 1100 );
```

выполнить в отладчике - то переход осуществляется тот час же после запуска.

Понять не получается - где зарыта собака.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я могу судить, и на сайте, и здесь Ваш код работает.

```js
jQuery('a[href^="#"]').click(function () { 
    elementClick = jQuery(this).attr("href");
    destination = jQuery(elementClick).offset().top;
    jQuery('html,body').animate( { scrollTop: (destination - 140) }, 1100 );        
    return false;
});
```

```css
.block {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:lightgreen;
  margin-top:5px;
}
a[href^="#"] {
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#b1">Go to 1</a> 
<a href="#b2">Go to 2</a> 
<a href="#b3">Go to 3</a> 
<a href="#b4">Go to 4</a> 
<a href="#b5">Go to 5</a> 
<a href="#b6">Go to 6</a> 
<a href="#b7">Go to 7</a> 
<a href="#b8">Go to 8</a> 
<a href="#b9">Go to 9</a> 
<a href="#b10">Go to 10</a> 
<a href="#b11">Go to 11</a> 
<a href="#b12">Go to 12</a> 
<a href="#b13">Go to 13</a> 
<a href="#b14">Go to 14</a> 
<a href="#b15">Go to 15</a> 
<a href="#b16">Go to 16</a> 
<div class="block" id="b1">1</div>
<div class="block" id="b2">2</div>
<div class="block" id="b3">3</div>
<div class="block" id="b4">4</div>
<div class="block" id="b5">5</div>
<div class="block" id="b6">6</div>
<div class="block" id="b7">7</div>
<div class="block" id="b8">8</div>
<div class="block" id="b9">9</div>
<div class="block" id="b10">10</div>
<div class="block" id="b11">11</div>
<div class="block" id="b12">12</div>
<div class="block" id="b13">13</div>
<div class="block" id="b14">14</div>
<div class="block" id="b15">15</div>
<div class="block" id="b16">16</div>
```